# USB mouse buttons stop working when laptop lid is closed

Tags: fedora, systemd, lxde

I'm running an LXDE/Fedora 34 spin on my old Dell laptop, docked to a Dell PR03X station.  The dock has my USB-attached keyboard and mouse, and I have an external screen attached to the laptop's HDMI (PR03X has no HDMI, only DP or DVI; intend to transition to dock once I get a long-enough cable).

In general, I want to run this laptop closed and hidden away, nearly always attached to the dock.

However, when I close the lid, after a few seconds, the USB mouse buttons stop responding.  The cursor still moves fine but most windows ignore the button presses (window frames don't focus; no response to clicks).  As soon as I open the lid again, buttons work as normal.

When running `xev`, I can see movement and button 1 events when clicking left button over the tester window; no button 3 events for right button (I can see both fine when the lid is up).

`watch -n2 lsusb -t` shows no changes to the connected USB devices.  `tail -F /var/log/messages` shows `systemd-login` acknowledging the lid close/open, but no
pertinent USB messages (at least, that *I* recognise).

`/etc/systemd/login.conf` has...

```
#HandleLidSwitch=suspend
#HandleLidSwitchExternalPower=suspend
#HandleLidSwitchDocked=ignore
```

...and these seem to be correct (in that it does not suspend/sleep when docked, and does when *not* docked) -- it's just the external mouse becomes nearly useless.

I've exhausted my knowledge here -- I don't know if it's a Fedora thing, an LXDE/Openbox thing, a SystemD thing, or simply a limit of the hardware.

Can anyone else shed any light?  Would moving to an I3 or Sway spin make any difference to this (a potential change I'm looking at since LXDE doesn't seem to be as well-supported any more)?